# unit testing for pagination

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

How to get the (List)SetCon.getRecords() in test class which is used in pagination.can anyone explain me exactly what it means?

```
      public class customcontroller{

        public Map<Id,wrapperlst> mplg{get;set;}

        public List<Wrapper> wrapperlst{
                      get{

                          List<Wrapper> wrap = new List<Wrapper>();

                            if(maplg.keySet()!=null){
                                for (X__c lg : (List<X__c>)SetCon.getRecords() ){

                                     if (maplg.get(lg.Id)!=null){
                                         wrap.add(mmaplg.get(lg.Id));
                                     } 
                                } 
                            }

                          return wrap;
                      }
                      set;

             }     

   public class wrapper{

       public X__C xc{get;set;}
       public boolean selected {get;set;}

      public wrapper(X__c xc1 , boolean selected){
        xc=xc1;
        selected = true;
}


    }
}
```

unable to cover the code in test class in for loop

```
for (X__c lg : (List<X__c>)SetCon.getRecords() ){

                                     if (maplg.get(lg.Id)!=null){
                                         wrap.add(mmaplg.get(lg.Id));
                                     }
```

I have written the code in test class :

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.PAGE_NAME; 
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController Con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lIST<X__x>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this test method. As you did not provide complete code modify the test method as necessary.

```
@isTest
public class sample_test
{
   static testMethod void sampletestmethod()
   {
        //----Insert records
        //----Here your object is X__c
        //----Pass inserted List<X__c> listXs to standardsetcontroller

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.VfpageName);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController sc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(listXs);
        customcontroller controller = new customcontroller(sc);

        //----Populate values in maplg
        //----Then verify
        System.assert(!controller.wrapperlst.isEmpty());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a custom controller how can we put 'ApexPages.StandardSetController sc' to controller .directly can we add it?

Comment: @sfdclearner Yes. You can pass `sc` directly. See my updated code.

Comment: @Reshma- how can we pass **SC** to controller other than mentioned above because if we pass to the SC to controller it throws error as constructor not defined.

Comment: @sfdclearner You should create a constructor in controller like `customcontroller(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following example of code to set that records

```
Test.startTest();
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.YOUR_PAGE);
ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lstAccount);
stdSetController.setSelected(lstAccount);
YOUR_Extension ext = new YOUR_Extension(stdSetController);
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: can you explain what does this means -  **(List<X__c>)SetCon.getRecords()**  and how to get this list?

Comment: X__c is a name of your custom object.  to populate this list you need to use the next line of my post: ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lstXCustomObjects); and then result of  (List<X__c>)SetCon.getRecords() will be lstXCustomObjects